# Vertical alignment when using Overflow Hidden

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having no luck trying to align some text.
I tested with the Overflow Hidden value removed but still couldn't get it looking how I would like.

Here is a codepen page example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXrPGJ

HTML

```
<div>
 <article>
  <section>
   <h2 class="colourtitle">
    <img class="sideimage" src="http://placehold.it/256x256">
    I'm glad I wrap, wish I was vert mid
   </h2>
  </section>
 <article>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

body {
    font: 16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 1.5em !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.colourtitle {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-width: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.sideimage {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    max-width: 70px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

I have Top Padding on my header tag, because on my actual page there will be many of these stacked, so just creates a nice white space.

I have set the Overflow Hidden, so that when viewed on a mobile screen the text wraps as I wish, and does not sit beneath the image.

```
h2 {
padding-top: 1.5em !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

You can see I'm using a thumb image, which has a right side border to it.
Along with an H2 tag, and that's all using a bottom side border.

But, I would like the text to be a little bit lower, so that it positions in the middle vertically, but still does the wrapping when needed on small screens.

I hope that is clear, and that someone can help me out with a snipped of code required. Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry Paulie_D, I didn't realise this. I see that Magnus has also kindly edited my code to include this, so I have just approved that for future if the codepen vanishes. Thanks again, Magnus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your browser support requirements, you could look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Looking at the provided link and code, you could get the text to position in the middle vertically by using display: flex and align-items: center.

```
.colourtitle {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;

  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus. This worked for me, just added those two lines of flexbox css and tested on my full page and worked a treat.